# Verify - if oblique line in matrix is equal

Tags: java

I wrote a program that finds out if matrix has 2 oblique lines that each oblique line has the same value. The lines does not have to be the same value.
for example:
4
1 2 3 4
2 1 4 0
1 3 1 2
7 1 2 2
for this example, output is false (there is only 1 oblique of 1,1,1)

another example:
4
1 7 2 4
2 1 0 3
7 2 3 2
9 3 2 7   for this example, output is true (there is 2 oblique: 3,3,3 and 2,2,2)

This is my code and i'm getting this problem:   "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at StdIn.readInt(StdIn.java:187)
    at CrossingDiagonals.main(CrossingDiagonals.java:18)"

```
 public static void main (String[] args)  {
   String size = StdIn.readLine();
   boolean indicator = false;
   int counter = 0;
   int matrixSize = Integer.parseInt(size);
   int [][] matrix = new int [matrixSize][matrixSize];
   for (int i=0; i <= matrixSize-1; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j <= matrixSize-1; j++) {
           matrix[i][j] = StdIn.readInt();
      }
   }
   for (int k=0; k <= matrixSize-2; k++) {
      for (int l=0; l <= matrixSize-2; l++) {
        if (matrix[k][l] == matrix[k+1][l+1])
          counter +=1;
        if (counter != 0 && matrix[k][l] == matrix[k+1][l+1]) {
          indicator = true; }
        else {
          indicator = false;
        }
      }
   }
    StdOut.println(indicator);
 }
```

}